# A person with a mindset of mutual growth

Tags: word-request

#### What is the one word for a person who not only causes his own growth of talent by his work, but also helps the community by helping the community members?

I am looking to apply the word in context of a school student. For example, such  school student would not only study his favorite subjects himself, but also start clubs at his school to help other similar minded students. Thus, he shows willingness to share knowledge while doing most of the hard work himself, and cause improvement in the entire lot of students instead of just himself.

I searched online but I don't think "collaborative" or "communal" are the best words in this case.

Comment: I would look under synonyms for _unselfish_.

Comment: @J.R. I checked. "altruistic, selfless, self-sacrificing; generous, philanthropic, public-spirited, humanitarian, humane, charitable, compassionate, benevolent, considerate, open-handed, magnanimous, liberal, noble" Honestly, all these words seem to me being much more applicable to a charitable organization than a simple school boy.

Comment: From a [2005 news story](http://articles.chicagotribune.com/2005-07-17/news/0507170307_1_half-blood-prince-potter-books-potter-fans): _hundreds of Potter fans lined up Friday outside the Magic Tree Book Shop in Oak Park awaiting the release of the sixth book in the popular series about **a benevolent boy wizard** and his battles against the forces of evil._ From a [tragic news story](http://www.al.com/news/index.ssf/2014/11/mom_describes_daylong_descent.html): _She said he was **a compassionate boy** who had decided this year he wanted to send toys to children in Africa._

Comment: @J.R. Ok, not the best words that I was looking for, but "compassionate" will still fit. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Gathering answers from comments, based on those that I consider most appropriate:

- altruistic
- benevolent
- public-spiritied
- generous

I would, personally, say that compassionate is not the best fit at all. It implies some of the same things, but not so much going out of one's way to help others.

Answer (score -1):

I would simply call it a **leader**.

> A leader is the person who leads or commands a group or an organization. A leader must have a groth mindset, both toward himself and his group/organization.